# How to secure API endpoints so only our code can use them?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have some Web API endpoints that I'd like to guarantee only our apps\code can access.

We've implemented a token-based authentication system.  The problem is someone could potentially inspect the traffic from the desktop, pull the tokens out, and script calls against our endpoints with the sniffed token.

Basically, I want to guarantee API calls only comes from our client code.  I've thought of potentially encrypting a token client side, then decrypting server side to check the source, but because our client javascript code can be inspected the method of encryption could potentially be reproduced.

I'm sure there are canned solutions out there... I'm just not sure where to start.   Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, if you have an api endpoint, consider it callable from anything. Because it is. You can authenticate a user, but that user is then authenticated to access your api with any utility (if you are using javascript as one of the clients). So the best solution is don't let them do anything dangerous. Double check everything on the backend.

Comment: See also this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118096/how-to-prove-that-client-side-javascript-is-secure

Comment: And also: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: Oh, also, you can use a web token with an expiration date to minimize the possibility of using another tool to access the api, but that doesn't eliminate it.